# SQL Server. Имя сервера

Tags: sql, sql-server

Поставил себе в учебных целях MS SQL Server Express.

Чтоб приступить к работе, нужно указать `"Имя сервера"`. Списка выбора никакого нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Возможно я не установил ещё пару файлов, где есть эти сервера. При скачке гугл мне давал 5 файлов, я установил только:

> - SQLManagementStudio_x64_RUS.exe

Ещё остались 4:

> - SQLEXPR_x64_RUS.exe
> - SqlLocaLDB.MSI
> - SQLEXPRADV_x64_RUS.exe
> - SQLEXPRWT_x64_RUS.exe

Файл `SqlLocaLDB.MSI` пытался установить, но выдало сообщение, что уже есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLManagementStudio_x64_RUS - это только клиент для MS SQL, сервера в этом пакете нет.

SqlLocaLDB обычно ставится вместе с Visual Studio. Если желаете использовать LocalDB - напишите (localdb)\чтонибудь вместо имени сервера. К примеру, Entity Framework по умолчанию использует сервер (localdb)\v12.

Но базы данных SqlLocaLDB доступны только одному пользователю, если предполагается работать с веб-проектами - то лучше поставить нормальный сервер. SQLEXPR_x64_RUS, например.

PS только когда будете ставить SQLEXPR_x64_RUS - не забудьте запомнить имя экземпляра, а то...

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!)