# Я установил MS SQL Server LocalDB, как теперь к нему подключиться?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-localdb

Managment Studio установился, но я не могу подключится к базе, по причине того, что она отсутствует (или не запущена).

В SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager ничего нету:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Среди служб windows есть и запущен только SQL Server VSS Writer.
При попытке зайти через Managment Studio:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачивал с [www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299).

Уже скачал все файлы, запускал все пункты меню установщиков - ничего.

В качестве варианта: думаю удалить все и поставить заново. Но оно связано с Visual Studio и я не знаю, как оно себя поведет (поломает все?!)

Как установить службу SQL сервера, чтобы можно было войти через Managment Studio?

Дополнения:
Команда osql -L пишет, что нет серверов.

Comment: После установки все остальное делается ручками из командной строки. По ссылке все есть:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3):

`LocalDB` работает без служб, неудивительно что список пуст.

При этом у каждого пользователя свой набор баз, что создаст кучу трудностей при web-разработке. И удаленно подключиться к `LocalDB` нельзя.

Если вас такой вариант устраивает, просто используйте в качестве имени сервера `(localdb)\что-угодно`. Инстанс `LocalDB` будет создан и запущен автоматически.

Если не устраивает - установите, собственно, серверный вариант SQL Server.

Comment: при попытке запустить вручную через консоль sqlservr.exe, я получаю ошибкy "Your SQL Server installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with (Error generating instance ID from name". Где я могу скачать серверный вариант? Можно ссылку?

Comment: Что именно вы пытаетесь запустить вручную через sqlservr.exe, если у вас ничего не установлено? Не надо ничего запускать отдельно, `LocalDB` запускается по требованию. Если так хочется по-администрировать, используйте `SqlLocalDB.exe` из папки `Tools\Binn` - но это необязательно.

Comment: Скачать же обычный сервер вы можете по той самой ссылке, что привели в своем вопросе. Только внимательнее выбирайте компонент.

Comment: как называется файл?

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, мой первый ответ еще раз. Там перечислены все файлы, с описанием того, что они делают.

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит так, будто SQL Server не установлен. Что именно вы скачивали и устанавливали?

Гляньте вот сюда, возможно, у вас та же самая проблема: [SQL Sever. Имя сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416588/sql-sever-%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/416594)

Comment: я только что скачать LocalDB 32BIT\SqlLocalDB.msi. В установщике были пункты "remove" и "repair". Я сначала удалил сервер (которого так и нигде нету) Затем запустил исталятор опять и ничего в службах не появилось - все как и было.

Comment: возможно он установился, но не прописался в службах. Можете мне подсказать имя файла сервера, чтобы я поискал его среди программ?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог запуск самого скаченного `SqlLocalDB.msi` и далее запуск SSMS, ввод `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` в поле `server name`.